# Urllib reads wrong website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web, urllib

I want to extract some information on a website, however urllib doesn't extract the same as the website shows in my browser.

```html
generic_link_seq = "http://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/yeastmine/sequenceExporter.do?object=1016810"

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(generic_link_seq).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"lxml")
text = soup.get_text().replace("\n", "")
print(text)
```

The real content of the site begins with:

> S000006360
>   atgaacagacaggaatccataaattcgtttaattcagacgaaacatcttcgttgtctgat
>   gtagaaagtcagcagccgcaacaatatatcccttcagagagtggatctaaatccaacatg
>   gctcctaatcaactgaagttgacccggacggaaaccgtgaagtcattgcaggac...

And the output that python gives me begins with:

> YeastMine: HomejQuery && jQuery(function() {    if (typeof intermine !== 'undefined' && intermine.options) {        intermine.options.CDN.server = "http://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/CDN/";    }});Search and retrieve S. cerevisiae data with YeastMine, populated by SGD and powered by InterMine.Data Updated on: Feb-6-2017          Home          Templates          Lists          QueryBuilder                   Tools...

Comment: The issue could be in authentication / veritication process. I couldn't reproduce your error, maybe I don't have proper permissions to view the site you linked. Keep in mind urllib by default sets the `User-Agent` to `Python-urllib/X.X` and this can cause the server sends you different response because you are treated like unauthenticated user which could be a bot. Please try getting the proper response using `curl` and after that make proper request in python

Comment: I tried different user-agent strings and it didn't help so I'm not sure that's the issue. This is the code I run: import urllib2
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request('http://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/yeastmine/sequenceExporter.do?object=1016810', None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print(html)

Comment: You might be redirected. That's something the browser can handle and your current code doesn't.

Comment: I've tried every single thing on here described and still didn't work, but thanks guys =)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `requests.Session` ( you need to get some cookies first )

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

generic_link_seq = "http://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/yeastmine/sequenceExporter.do?object=1016810"
ses = requests.Session()
ses.get(generic_link_seq).text
sauce = ses.get(generic_link_seq).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce,"lxml")
text = soup.get_text().replace("\n", "")
print(text)
```

Result :

> >S000006360atgaacagacaggaatccataaattcgtttaattcagacgaaacatcttcgttgtctgat gtagaaagtcagcagccgcaacaatatatcccttcagagagtggatctaaatccaacatg gctcctaatcaactgaagttgacccggacggaaaccgtgaagtcattgcaggac...

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!